# efficient projection of a bipartite graph in python (using networkx)

Tags: python, performance, loops, python-3.x, networkx

Using the networkx module, I do some network analysis under Python 3.2, where I need to project a bipartite graph (of inmates linked to their cell: input graph B in the code below) to a subgraph (linking cellmates to each other if both had an overlapping spell in the same cell: using the input of set nodes defining the inmate-nodes of graph B, generating output graph G). I don't need a special algorithm to come up with any or an optimal matching, I just need to collect all links that satisfy some conditions. Thus other SO posts I found do not really apply. But:

My current code is blowing up (RAM-, swap-, and CPU-wise) as I give it more and more data. Please let me know if you see ways to streamline the code below with 5 layers of loops. I am not sure any knowledge of networkx is necessary or details of my labeling of edge attributes is relevant. Thanks!

```
def time_overlap_projected_graph_parallel(B, nodes):
    G=nx.MultiGraph()
    G.add_nodes_from((n,B.node[n]) for n in nodes)
    for u in nodes:
        unbrs = set(B[u])
        nbrs2 = set((n for nbr in unbrs for n in B[nbr])) - set([u])
        for v in nbrs2:
            for mutual_cell in set(B[u]) & set(B[v]):
                for uspell in B.get_edge_data(u,mutual_cell).values():
                    ustart = uspell[1]
                    uend = uspell[2]
                    for vspell in B.get_edge_data(v,mutual_cell).values():
                        vstart = vspell[1]
                        vend = vspell[2]
                        if uend > vstart and vend > ustart:
                            ostart = max(ustart,vstart)
                            oend = min(uend,vend)
                            olen = (oend-ostart+1)/86400
                            ocell = mutual_cell
                            if (v not in G[u] or ostart not in [ edict[1] for edict in G[u][v].values() ]):
                                G.add_edges_from([(u,v,{0: olen,1: ostart,2: oend,3: ocell})])
    return G
```

Comment: Can you clarify more? I guess B is the original graph, then what is nodes? And I'm not sure I understand what you want. You have a bipartite graph of cells and inmates. Then you want a graph of what? Just inmates? Connected if they are in the same cell?

Comment: Thanks, Avaris, you understood correctly, but I'll clarify my question too.

Comment: OK. The term "subgraph" threw me, since technically the new graph won't be a subgraph. In that case, why don't you just iterate over cells and connect a cell's neighbors in the new graph?

Comment: loops are not so efficient in python (http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops).  If your 2 inner loops get large, it might indeed become very slow.  What are the typical sizes of the things you are looping over?

Comment: @Avaris: I think this is what I am doing in the code posted, but I am burning resources at an unacceptable rate. I am looking for ways to cut down the memory use.

Comment: @steabert:
nodes: hundreds of thousand (outmost loop);
nbrs2: cells an imate has been in, at most a few dozens (not checked);
mutual_cell: a few only, though the loop definition calls sells of u and v too, dozens of each;
vspell: in the single digits (number of overlapping spells between people);
Does this sound unreasonable to use 30 GBs of RAM and 40+ GBs of swap space? I might be missing something...

Comment: Trying to understand from the code (correct me if I am wrong): nodes = inmates, u = first inmate, unbrs = cells that u was in, nbrs2 = all inmates that stayed in unbrs, v = another inmate, mutual_cell = a cell they shared.

Comment: @Avaris: I think you are correct. This must have been my intention. (FYI: I adapted some other code for this over the summer, and checked that it worked in test data. That's why I am a bit cautious about which object is which. But I think this is how these loops work.)

Comment: So the question is still not worth an upvote? ;)

Comment: Then 2nd (v) and 3rd (mutual_cell) loops look like backwards to me. Try switching them: i.e. `for mutual_cell in B[u]` and then `for v in B[mutual_cell]`. Then of course you have to skip if v==u.

Comment: If you have so much nodes, it could be either just the line `G.add_nodes_from(...)` since that has a loop too, or the rest of your code that takes a lot of time.  Did you do any profiling?

Comment: @steabert: I did not learn enough from profiling, though I tried some.

Comment: @Avaris: Please see the revised code I post as an answer, whether that does the same but without sets. Things might get much better with iterators, and I only used the sets to jump over u==v, I think. Still, it would be an important lesson for me if these supposedly small sets were the ones taking up tens of GBs.

Comment: update: I cannot (self-)answer for another 8 hours with my reputation, sorry. And the revised code is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 3):

One could now use bipartite graphs I guess. Like

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite

B.add_nodes_from(inmates_list, bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(cells_list, bipartite=1)

inmates = set(n for n,d in B.nodes(data=True) if d['bipartite']==0)
cells = = set(B) - inmates
G = bipartite.projected_graph(B, inmates)
```

(http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.bipartite.html)

Comment: In NetworkX 2.0, you can do something like `inmates = {n for n, is_inmate in B.nodes(data='bipartite') if is_inmate}` which is a little nicer (assuming you reverse the `bipartite` attribute values 1 and 0).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take. Depending on average inmates per cell, it might improve performance. If you have a better way to get cells (e.g. node properties?), replace

```
cells = [n for n in B.nodes() if n[0] not in nodes]
```

with that (here I'm assuming nodes is a list of all inmates).

```
from itertools import combinations

def time_overlap_projected_graph_parallel(B, nodes):
    G=nx.MultiGraph()
    G.add_nodes_from((n,B.node[n]) for n in nodes)
    cells = [n for n in B.nodes() if n[0] not in nodes]
    for cell in cells:
        for u,v in combinations(B[cell],2):
            for uspell in B.get_edge_data(u,cell).values():
                ustart = uspell[1]
                uend = uspell[2]
                for vspell in B.get_edge_data(v,cell).values():
                    vstart = vspell[1]
                    vend = vspell[2]
                    if uend > vstart and vend > ustart:
                        ostart = max(ustart,vstart)
                        oend = min(uend,vend)
                        olen = (oend-ostart+1)/86400
                        ocell = cell
                        if (v not in G[u] or ostart not in [ edict[1] for edict in G[u][v].values() ]):
                            G.add_edge(u,v,{0: olen,1: ostart,2: oend,3: ocell})
    return G
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this answer to suggest a few improvements. I will assume that your bipartite graph is not a multi graph but a normal `nx.Graph`. I changed `B` to `bi` and `G` to `uni` since upper case names are reserved for classes by convention. Btw, what if spells started and ended at the exact same time?

```python
def time_overlap_projected_graph_parallel(bi, nodes):
    uni = nx.MultiGraph()
    for u in nodes: #inmate
        uni.add_node(u) # do this to prevent iterating nodes twice
        u_adj = bi.adj[u] # bi.adj is a dict of dicts
        for (w, uw_attr) in u_adj.iteritems(): # cell
            w_adj = bi.adj[w]
            for (v, wv_attr) in w_adj.iteritems():#cellmate
                if v == u:
                    continue
                elif uni.has_edge(u, v): # avoid computing twice
                    continue
                for uspell in uw_attr.itervalues():
                    ustart = uspell[1]
                    uend = uspell[2]
                    for vspell in wv_attr.itervalues():
                        vstart = vspell[1]
                        vend = vspell[2]
                        if uend > vstart and vend > ustart:
                            ostart = max(ustart, vstart)
                            oend = min(uend, vend)
                            olen = (oend - ostart + 1) / 86400 # this assumes floats or Python 3 otherwise will be 0
                            ocell = w
                            # I would change this to uni.add_edge(u, v, length=olen, start=ostart, end=oend, cell=ocell)
                            # or to uni.add_edge(u, v, spell=[olen, ostart, oend, ocell])
                            uni.add_edge(u, v, **{0: olen, 1: ostart, 2: oend, 3: ocell})
    return uni
```

Comment: Thanks, I cannot rerun it now to check how much faster it is. Why exactly do you expect it to be faster? On the spells: I am OK dropping spells ending when they start as erroneous.

Comment: The main reason that this should be much faster is the check `uni.has_edge(u, v)`. Since you're looping over all nodes this will avoid a lot of steps when you're reaching the inverse `uni.had_edge(v, u)` will already be computed. Your code also check whether the intersection of a spell is already there in a list which is an `O(n)` operation. Not sure how long those lists are. The whole spell computation could be improved thinking about it. I'll edit accordingly. Overall, for very large networks `networkx` is probably not the right tool.

Comment: @László I was talking about the case `if uend >= vstart and vend >= ustart`.

Comment: Thanks, I think that would just double count the same things, no?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the revised code, which might do the same, but with iterators (though I also revised a few networkx-related function/method-calls --- but I'm still checking if I broke something):

```
def time_overlap_projected_graph_parallel(B, nodes):
    G=nx.MultiGraph()
    G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
    for u in G.nodes_iter():#inmate
        for w in B.neighbors_iter(u):#cell
            for v in B.neighbors_iter(w):#cellmate
                if v == u:
                    continue
                for uspell in B[u][w].values():
                    ustart = uspell[1]
                    uend = uspell[2]
                    for vspell in B[v][w].values():
                        vstart = vspell[1]
                        vend = vspell[2]
                        if uend > vstart and vend > ustart:
                            ostart = max(ustart,vstart)
                            oend = min(uend,vend)
                            olen = (oend-ostart+1)/86400
                            ocell = w
                            if (v not in G[u] or ostart not in [ edict[1] for edict in G[u][v].values() ]):
                                G.add_edges_from([(u,v,{0: olen,1: ostart,2: oend,3: ocell})])
    return G
```